# Microsoft Graph Api SDK: update Managed Metadata (Taxonomy)

Tags: c#, .net-core, sharepoint, microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-sdks

I need to update a Managed Metadata (Term) via Microsoft Graph Api Sdk for .Net.

I have all the information about the Term after the following call:

```
            var term = graphClient
            .Sites[mySite]
            .TermStore
            .Groups[myGroup] 
            .Sets[mySet]
            .Terms[myIdTerm]
            .Terms
            .Request()
            .GetAsync()
            .Result;
```

Taxonomy has a different approach comparing others metadata so I can't make the right call.

Comment: Could you specify what exactly do you want to update? Which properties?

Answer (score 0):

No, updating managed metadata columns (columns with terms / TaxonomyFields) are not supported through the graph API.

The same issue has been asked here: https://github.com/microsoftgraph/microsoft-graph-docs/issues/4911.

Comment: Are you sure?
In the same post you can find this: https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/130945/is-possible-to-update-metadata-type-collectionsp-taxonomy-taxonomyfieldva
and elsewhere:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55033458/cant-update-sharepoint-managed-meta-data-field-from-microsoft-graph-explorer