# Add term to listItem in Microsoft Graph API

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-sites

How do I add a `term` to a `listItem` in Microsoft Graph API?

For simple String types (ProductSegment in the example) I do the following:

```
PATCH https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites/{{sharepoint_site_id}}/lists/{{sharepoint_list_id}}/items/{{num}}/fields
{
    "DisplayedName": "asdasfsvsvdvsdbvdfb",
    "DocumentType": "FLYER",
    "ProductSegment": ["SEG1"],
    "TEST_x0020_2_x0020_ProductSegment": [{
        "TermGuid": "c252c37d-1fa3-4860-8d3e-ff2cdde1f673"
    }],
    "Active": true,
    "ProductSegment@odata.type": "Collection(Edm.String)",
    "TEST_x0020_2_x0020_ProductSegment@odata.type": "Collection(Edm.Term)"
}
```

Obviously it won't work for `TEST_x0020_2_x0020_ProductSegment`. But I just cannot find any hints in the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/listitem?view=graph-rest-1.0).

---

I got one step closer thanks to the duplicated issue. First I found the `name` (not the `id`) of the hidden field `TEST 2 ProductSegment_0` (notice the `_0` suffix). Then assembled the `term` value to send: `-1;#MyLabel|c352c37d-1fa3-4860-8d3e-ff2cdde1f673`.

```
PATCH https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites/{{sharepoint_site_id}}/lists/{{sharepoint_list_id}}/items/{{num}}/fields
{
    "DisplayedName": "asdasfsvsvdvsdbvdfb",
    "DocumentType": "FLYER",
    "ProductSegment": ["SEG1"],
    "i9da5ea20ec548bfb2097f0aefe49df8": "-1;#MyLabel|c352c37d-1fa3-4860-8d3e-ff2cdde1f673",
    "Active": true,
    "ProductSegment@odata.type": "Collection(Edm.String)"
}
```

and so I can add *one* item. I would need to add multiple, so I wanted to add the values to an array and set the field type (`i9da5ea20ec548bfb2097f0aefe49df8@odata.type`) to `Collection(Edm.String)`.

Now I get an error with the code `generalException` as opposed to an `invalidRequest`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I got it.

Thanks @Nikolay for the linked issue.

As I also added this to the end of the question, first you need the `name` (not the `id`!) of the hidden field `TEST 2 ProductSegment_0` (notice the `_0` suffix). Then assemble the term values to send: `-1;#MyLabel|c352c37d-1fa3-4860-8d3e-ff2cdde1f673` and `-1;#SecondLabel|1ef2af46-1fa3-4860-8d3e-ff2cdde1f673`, and separate them with `;#` (actually the content of the label is irrelevant but some string needs to be there).

Looks utterly ridiculous but works.

```
PATCH https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites/{{sharepoint_site_id}}/lists/{{sharepoint_list_id}}/items/{{num}}/fields
{
    "DisplayedName": "asdasfsvsvdvsdbvdfb",
    "DocumentType": "FLYER",
    "ProductSegment": ["SEG1"],
    "i9da5ea20ec548bfb2097f0aefe49df8": "-1;#MyLabel|c352c37d-1fa3-4860-8d3e-ff2cdde1f673";#-1;#SecondLabel|1ef2af46-1fa3-4860-8d3e-ff2cdde1f673,
    "Active": true,
    "ProductSegment@odata.type": "Collection(Edm.String)"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, graph API does not support updating SharePoint taxonomy. For now, you can go with classic SharePoint REST API for example to accomplish "advanced" things like updating taxonomy terms. Probably a duplicate of: [Can't Update Sharepoint Managed Meta Data Field from Microsoft Graph Explorer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55033458/cant-update-sharepoint-managed-meta-data-field-from-microsoft-graph-explorer)

Comment: Thanks. This is actually helpful. I managed to add already one term to an item. Now working on being able to add a list of terms. Anyhow I'll post my findings.